# Bare minimum install to get over "algorithm.sty" not found error

Tags: linux, latex, tex

On using `\usepackage{algorithm}`, I obtain the error that `algorithm.sty` is not found. At present, my way to get around this is to first search for this package via:

```
$ apt-file search "algorithm.sty"                                                                           
latexml: /usr/share/perl5/LaTeXML/Package/algorithm.sty.ltxml                                                                                                             
texlive-lang-arabic: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/simurgh/simurgh-algorithm.sty                                                                             
texlive-science: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
```

This tells me that `texlive-science` contains `algorithm.sty`. I then issue

`sudo apt-get install texlive-science`

This then indicates that around 100 MB of disk space will be used up on installing this package. (If I go ahead and install `texlive-science` package which uses up 100 MB of disk space, the `.tex` file compiles fine.)

It is not clear to me that I need to use 100 MB of disk space just to be able to compile my `.tex` file with `\usepackage{algorithm}`

Is there a more parsimonious/cheaper way to install *only* missing `.sty` files without having to install the entire package that it is a part of?

Comment: If you would use vanilla texlive instead of the one packaged for linux, you can install individual packages with `tlmgr install <packagename here>`. This would also give you more up-to-date versions of packages ...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do not actually want to install a full package. I only want to install a single file in that package -- `algorithm.sty` and its dependencies, in this case from `texlive-science`. The latter is quite huge containing 700 odd files. Please see https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-science/files/ out of which `algorithm.sty` is just a solitary lonely unassuming file!

Comment: The algorithm package only installs the actual latex package, e.g. the sty file and other files needed by this package. Real texlive does not use these strange linux packages with whole collections of packages.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. I will try it out and see if it would work. At present, I am running into a `verify_checksum returned -5` error which seems to be because my `tlmgr` is old. Let me figure that out and try the method you suggest.

Comment: That's why I suggest using vanilla texlive instead of the outdated stuff which comes with linux

Comment: Would you suggest following the method provided here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/254015 to install "vanilla" TexLive? Or, is there anything else that you would recommend? The method there seems quite complicated and still seems to be using linux's `apt-get` stuff.

Comment: I normally don't install with sudo and instead just give me writing access to `/usr/local/texlive/` (I'm on a single user system). The apt part in the linked answer is just for dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

`texlive` packages are not always named after the `.sty` file you are after unfortunately. But the apt-file search can help point to the package name.

In this case, `algorithms` (which you can see under the `texlive-science` `latex/` directory) is recognised.
Running `tlmgr install algorithms` worked for me.